# Changing Google Sheets Cell Value from JavaScript Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to change the value of a specific cell in Google Sheets based on a users selection from a dropdown menu. Also, might be worth mentioning that this dropdown menu is inside an HTML table generated from Sheets data. Everything works except for this one little thing. Help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML Snippet:

```
<select id="status" name="status">
    <option value="current" id="current"><?= tableData[i][j] ?></option>
    <option value="submitted" id="submitted">Submitted</option>
</select>
<script>
    let select = document.querySelector('#status');
    select.addEventListener('change', update(i, j));
</script>
```

Code.gs function:

```
var rfi= SpreadsheetApp.openById("REDACTED");
var sheet = rfi.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 

function update(i, j) {
    sheet.getRange(i, j).setValue("In Review");
}
```

Comment: When you select the option, you are selecting the value of tableData[i][j], not the i and j coordinates, so you cannot submit anything other than that value.

Comment: Where is i , j defined

Comment: i and j are defined in the for loops.

Comment: can you share a simplified spreadsheet to finalize my proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass coordinates, try

in html

```
<option value="<?=(i+1)+'|'+(j+1)?>" id="current"><?= tableData[i][j] ?></option>
```

in gs

```
function update(coord) {
  sheet.getRange(coord.split('|')[0], coord.split('|')[1]).setValue("In Review");
}
```

will be finalized after your spreadsheet is published

### sample

For instance, this works and shows how to transfer coordinates

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    <? var data = listOfItems(); ?>
  </script>
    <select id="choice" name="choice">
      <option value="" disabled selected >Choose ...</option>
        <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) { ?>
            <option value="<?=(i+1)+'|'+(j+1)?>" ><?=data[i][j]?></option>
          <? } ?>
        <? } ?>
    </select>
    <script>
      $('#choice').change(function(){ 
        google.script.run.update ($(this).val());
      });
    </script>
</body>
```

gs

```
function load() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('load')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle("test ...");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('mySheet')
function listOfItems() {
  return  sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
};
function update(coord){
  sheet.getRange(coord.split('|')[0], coord.split('|')[1]).setValue("In Review");
}
```

Comment: Hi, Mike thanks for taking the time to help me. Unfortunately when I replaced my function and "current" option with yours, it still didn't work. I'd be happy to share more of the code with you over email or screenshare.

Comment: I know I have to finalize. So please, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I updated my answer with a complete working example that shows how to transfer coordinates.